# Meteor and MongoDB: How to set an object in a table

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I have a problem with Meteor and MongoDB. I'm coding a little game. I use accounts-ui and when an account is created I add some fields to this account :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    user.money = 0;
    user.rate = 0;
    user.employees = [];
    return user;
})
```

As you can see, I have a table named "employees".

When the user will click on a button to hire an employee, I want to update this table. Imagine the user hire a programmer, I want to update my table like this :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    user.money = 0;
    user.rate = 0;
    user.employees = [{"programmer": 1}];
    return user;
})
```

If the user hire an other programmer I want to increment the number of programmer. And if the user hire a designer I want to add it to the table like this :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    user.money = 0;
    user.rate = 0;
    user.employees = [{"programmer": 2}, {"designer": 1}];
    return user;
})
```

I'm a beginner in Meteor and MongoDB, I don't understand how I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `employees` is a key-value pair as you described, I'd use an object instead of an array.

`user.employees = {};`

It makes MongoDB operations easier:

`Meteor.users.update({_id: someId}, {$inc: {"employees.programmer": 1}});`

This server-side code adds one to the user's programmers. If the user doesn't have a programmer yet, this code will create the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `employees`attribute to the user like this :

```
Accounts.createUser( {
   username: 'test',
   email: 'email@email.com',
   password: 'test',
   employees: {} 
});
```

And update the `employees` :

- Add an employee

  `Meteor.users.update(idUser, {$addToSet: {employees: {'a': 1}}});
  Meteor.users.update(idUser, {$addToSet: {employees: {'b': 1}}});`
- Increment the number of employee `a` :

  `Meteor.users.update(idUser, {$pull: {employees: {'a': 1}}});
  Meteor.users.update(idUser, {$addToSet: {employees: {'a': 2}}});`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write query like this:

```
If( programmer hired ) {
   Meteor.users.update({_id: someId}, {$inc: {"employees.programmer": 1}});
} else if ( designer hired ) {
   Meteor.users.update({_id: someId}, {$inc: {"employees.designer": 1}});
} else if ( programmer and designer hired ) {
  Meteor.users.update({_id: someId}, {$inc: {"employees.programmer": 1, "employees.designer": 1}});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will use the solution of aedm because I will have a lot of kind of employee so if I use if/else it will be difficult to maintain the code :)